# What is the childView and index of a recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, view, android-recyclerview

In the doc it says that the position is 
Position: The position of a data item within an Adapter.
which I get, its the position of the item in the recyclerview, but I do not get what a Index: The index of an attached child view as used in a call to getChildAt(int). Contrast with Position.
Is the child view the inflated xml file, and if so what is the index of it?

Answer (score 0):

You have actually 3 values for each item:

- Adatper Position
- Layout Position
- and an ID, if you use stableIds, will default to `-1` for all items.

---

**Adapter position** is the one you will most likely use. If you have your data

```
String[] myListData;
```

the adapter position is the one `bindViewHolder(VH holder, int adapterPosition)` gets called with. It identifies your objects you want to display.

---

If you have a list with 1000 items, only a handful (e.g. 10) get displayed at once—this is why you use a recyclerView and not a LinearLayout.

The index of the view, or layout position, is of interest to you, if you want to know *where* your item gets displayed. If you scroll, the first 10 items might not be visible, and the 11th item could be the first visible one—thus having `layoutPosition==0, or index==0`—being the top of your scrolled list.

You will only need this, if you intend to do some custom drawing, `RecyclerView.ItemDecoration` or some other scroll / state listening. For the basic use of a recyclerView the index or layout position can be safely ignored.